# How to pass basic auth Public key and Private key in header angularjs

Tags: angularjs, basic-authentication

How can we pass the public and private key of basic auth in $http.put?

Answer (score 1):

You can create httpProvider interceptor:

```
angular.module('app').factory('apiInterceptor', function(token){
    return {
        request: function(req) {
            req.headers.Authorization = token.get();
            return req;
        }
    }).config(function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('apiInterceptor');
    }).provider('token', function() {
         var token = '';
         return {
             get: function() {
                 return token;
             },
             set: function(t) {
                 token = t;
             }
         }
    }).controller('myController', function(token) {
         token.set('your token');
    });
```

Something like this.

Comment: How to pass basic authentication and its keys like public and private key in angular controller?

Comment: You can create angular provider which will hold your informations.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to do it in the configuration (you app.js file) or you could do that in your controller as well

```
app.run(['$http', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;
}]);

app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = /* ... */;
}])
```

Comment: How to pass basic authentication and its keys like public and private key in angular controller?

Comment: .controller('Controller Name', ['$http', function($http) {
   $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + login + ':' + password);
}]);

Comment: Also you can make a factory out of it and then use the config within the factory to send the headers